# command not found - error in exec() command

Tags: php

I run this from php file

```
exec("epm package");
```

i got below error in error_log

```
sh: epm: command not found
```

I tested manually in terminal it works fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try putting in a full path name:

`exec("/path/to/epm package");`

Your webserver process won't necessarily be set up with the same configuration as your own account.

Answer (score 3):

sounds like `epm` isn't in the PATH environment variable for the user your webserver is running (probably apache). to solve this, do one of these:

- add the path to `epm` to the webserver-users PATH
- provide the full path for your command to be executed (`/whatever/folder/epm package`)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the user you are testing with in the terminal and the webserver user running your PHP are different. You need to make sure directory for the epm package is exported to the PATH environment variable for the webserver user.