# Adding git-ftp to my environment for php

Tags: php, gitolite, git-ftp

I've installed [git-ftp](https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp) onto my CentOS Server so that I can do deployments from an activeCollab installation running the ac_gitolite module.

Everything installed fine and the app lives at

```
/usr/local/bin/git-ftp
```

When I log into the server via ssh I can run git-ftp commands without the full path, but when attempting to use PHP to run commands with exec ie:

```
exec ("git-ftp --version 2>&1", $output);
```

I receive the following error:

```
sh: git-ftp: command not found
```

Is there an environment path I need to specify somewhere specifically for PHP, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The two options discussed in "[command not found - error in `exec()` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459070/command-not-found-error-in-exec-command)" are:

- One easy solution would be to put the full path of the `git-ftp` executable.
- The other is to add git-ftp to the php server user's `PATH`.

Comment: Great, how do I input option 2.  My linux command line is not the best? Thanks @VonC!

Comment: @VinceKronlein you need to access to the user account (let's say '`phpuser`') which runs the web php server, and modify it `/home/phpuser/.profile`, adding `export PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/git-ftp/parent/directory`

Comment: This will probably work.  You say path to it's parent directory? I'm on a WHM/cPanel server and in my home dir I see, .bash_profile, and .bashrc.  Or do I make a new file called .profile?  Thanks again.

Comment: @VinceKronlein the idea is *not* to reference the `git-ftp` executable itself in the `PATH`, but only its parent directory. In your case: `/usr/local/bin/`, so `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin/`

Comment: Yeah I tried it in both .profile and .bash_profile no luck, still getting the same error.  Do I need to restart apache or ssh or something?

Comment: @VinceKronlein no need to restart anything, but you need to be sure of which account is running the php webserver.

Comment: Hmmm.  By running ps aux | grep apache it looks like it's either root or nobody that's running the server. I would assume then that would be the same user that runs PHP.  and of course neither of them have folders in /home/ ... It was my belief that under a cPanel install using SuPHP, PHP runs under whatever user the website is under. Running exec("whoami") always produces the current user where the file is run from.

Comment: Yep ... see here: http://www.ndchost.com/wiki/cpanel/enable-suphp so adding that file to the home dir of the user where the site is housed should do the trick ... except it doesn't. Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: @VinceKronlein can you check if it works if you specify the full path, as a temporary workaround, just to be able to move forward?

Comment: yeah it does work with the full path for sure ... it just seems strange that I can't call it by name as the /usr/local/bin directory IS in my path.  Head scratcher.